# Iterating through dynamic WPF Treeview items

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

So, I want the user to be able to build a treeview by himself.
The treeview basically contains two kinds of items:

- item (`MenuItem` inheriting `TreeviewMenuItem`)
- submenu (`MenuSubmenu` inheriting `TreeviewMenuItem`, contains a `List<MenuItem>`)

Treeview uses an **ItemsSource** which is a `List<TreeviewMenuItem>`.

User can add submenus and items into the submenus.
There is no limit to the level of nodes.

```
public abstract class TreeviewMenuItem
{
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual string DisplayName { get => Text; }
    public virtual MenuSubmenu ParentMenu { get; set; } = null;
}

public class MenuSubmenu : TreeviewMenuItem
{
    public override string DisplayName { get => Text + " [" + Items.Count + "]"; }
    public List<MenuItem> Items { get; set; }

    public MenuSubmenu(MenuSubmenu parent = null)
    {
        ParentMenu = parent;
        Items = new List<MenuItem>();
    }
}

public class MenuItem : TreeviewMenuItem
{
    public MenuItem(MenuSubmenu parent = null)
    {
        ParentMenu = parent;
    }
}
```

Here is an example of a menu the user can create:
[image: The menu]

When the user has finished building the treeview, it can export it to XML.
The problem is: How can I iterate through all the nodes?

As you can see, since my submenus contains a `List<MenuItem>` which can also contain submenus (etc.), I can't use a simple loop through the ItemsSource.

I have no idea how to handle the dynamic amount of submenus with all the items it contains...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To analyze the tree the simplest method could be to write a recursive method.
Something like this:

```
    public void AnalyzeTree(List<TreeviewMenuItem> menuItems)
    {
        foreach (var menuItem in menuItems)
        {
            switch (menuItem)
            {
                case MenuSubmenu submenu:
                    // TODO: submenu action
                    AnalyzeTree(submenu.Items);
                    break;
                case MenuItem item:
                    // TODO: item action
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I finally had the time to put your solution in place. It works great! I didn't think of using recursive methods (I didn't really had the need to at this time). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First question, why do you need to iterate through items? Just take the base of the tree and serialize it, XML serialization will handle all the children. 
It is important to add `XmlInclude` attributes for all derived classes and omit loops using `XmlIgnore`
On your example:

```
 [XmlInclude(typeof(MenuSubmenu))]
 [XmlInclude(typeof(MenuItem))]
 public abstract class TreeviewMenuItem
{ 
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual string DisplayName { get => Text; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public virtual MenuSubmenu ParentMenu { get; set; } = null;
}

public class MenuSubmenu : TreeviewMenuItem
{        
    public override string DisplayName { get => Text + " [" + Items.Count + "]"; }       
          [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(TreeviewMenuItem)),   
           XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(MenuSubmenu))] 
    public List<MenuItem> Items { get; set; }

    public MenuSubmenu(MenuSubmenu parent = null)
    {
        Items = new List<MenuItem>();
    }
}
public class MenuItem : TreeviewMenuItem
{
    public MenuItem(MenuSubmenu parent = null)
    {
        ParentMenu = parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know there was a way to save treeview items as xml data. But I wanted to iterate through the items since it allows me to write it with my own syntax. It is not only to store data, the xml file is later read by another independent software which understands a certain syntax. But this solution seems efficient to store data as XML, so thank you for sharing :)